# Adding 10+ Sites to MSM - Does this workaround sound crazy?

Tags: multi-site-manager, database, ee1, database-error

Here's the situation.  I tried to add a 10th site to my MSM and I got an SQL error that effectively says, you can't add another column to the exp_weblog_data table.

`Description: Can't create table 'simplifiedsafety_eu.#sql-1935_220d4' (errno: 139)`

So I researched a bit and basically this boils down to a poorly designed database (yeah I know it has to do with fulltext searching yada yada) and the constraints of mySQL.

**So what is a developer to do?**

Well here's what I came up with and I wanted to run this by some people in the community before I test this out:

1) Create another www directory (called www2) where I pointed the URL for the additional sites

2) Create a copy of the current ee database.

3) Create symbolic links to all files and directories in the original director *EXCEPT* for the system/config.php

4) Point the new system/config.php at the copy of the database.

5) Delete most of the sites out of the ee that's pointing at the db copy.  (Of course I could copy the site I needed first)

If my theory holds then I could maintain ONE code base, but have two separate databases (and two separate config files), and everything else would be unified.  Assumedly this would allow me to double the number of MSM sites that I'm running.

The only disadvantage that I could see is if I wanted to make a duplicate of a site that was in the other database.

I realize that the control panels would only show the sites in the database that it was pointed at, but that's not a problem for me either.

Your thoughts here:

Comment: You may want to check the licensing requirements with EllisLab for this kind of setup. You may need to purchase additional licenses but they'll need to confirm.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl yes, I would not plan on violating the number of MSM sites.  I'm just wondering about the technical possibility.

Comment: Really you'd just need to try it. I don't think most of us have been in this dilemma. I sure haven't in all my years with EE.